# Dropdown Menu conditionals for two options in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating a form in HTML with two options: Phone and Email.

Please see this for the complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/f6xhbcys/

So when a user clicks on phone, they are presented with divs in the .contact-phone-option div, and if the user clicks on email, they are presented with the div in the .contact-email-option

The code I wrote isn't working, even though I've checked over and over again the matching IDs I've used, and can't seem to figure out why nothing is happening when an option is selected.

HTML:
        
            Preferred Method of Contact
         
              Select
              Phone
              Email

```
    <div class="contact-phone-option">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label>Phone</label>
          <input id="contact-phone" name="contact-phone" value="" pattern="^\(?\d{3}\)?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$" type="tel" required/>
        </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6">
          <label>Best Time to Call</label>
          <input id="contact-time" name="contact-time" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="col-lg-12 contact-email-option">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input id="contact-email" name="contact-email" value="" required type="email">
      </div>
```

jQuery:

```
// Contact Form Dropdown menu                                                                                    
$('.contact-phone-option, .contact-email-option').hide();
$('#contact-method-menu').change(function () {
    if ($('#contact-phone').is(':selected')) {
        $('.contact-phone-option').show();
        $('.contact-email-option').hide();
    }
    if ($('#contact-email').is(':selected')) {
        $('.contact-email-option').show();
        $('.contact-phone-option').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle.net

Comment: This does not look like a complete example. What is `$("#contact-phone")` and `$("#contact-email")`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f6xhbcys/  I've put the complete code here

Comment: Fixed your Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/dv9gc009/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking `$('#contact-phone')` and `$('#contact-email')` for `:selected`.  Since they're `input`s, that will never happen.  You would check the `option` for `:selected`.  However, even that step isn't needed, since you just need the `.val()` of the `select`.  You can then check the value and match for "Phone" and "Email".

Side note, your fiddle was missing jQuery!

```js
     // Contact Form Dropdown menu       
    $('.contact-phone-option, .contact-email-option').hide();
    $('#contact-method-menu').on('change', function() {
      if ($('#contact-method-menu').val() == 'Phone') {
        $('.contact-phone-option').show();
        $('.contact-email-option').hide();
      } else if ($('#contact-method-menu').val() == 'Email') {
        $('.contact-email-option').show();
        $('.contact-phone-option').hide();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <label>Preferred Method of Contact</label>
  <select id="contact-method-menu" name="contact-method-menu" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
    <option value="Email">Email</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="contact-phone-option">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input id="contact-phone" name="contact-phone" value="" pattern="^\(?\d{3}\)?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\\
d{4}$" type="tel" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <label>Best Time to Call</label>
    <input id="contact-time" name="contact-time" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 contact-email-option">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input id="contact-email" name="contact-email" value="" required type="email">
</div>
```

Another side note is for this line:

```
$('.contact-phone-option, .contact-email-option').hide();
```

You'll end up seeing a flash of content going this route, since they won't `hide()` until jQuery is loaded.  You should consider hiding in the CSS, and showing from there.  You could also shorten the `show()` and `hide()` calls to:

```
$('.contact-phone-option, .contact-email-option').toggle();
```

Comment: Thank you! Still a beginner to jQuery so this explanation was helpful.